# Kubernetes NGINX Ingress - giving 503 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus, nginx-ingress, strimzi

i've an Ingress created, and i'm trying to access Prometheus using pathRouting

Ingress yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
  name: ingress-prometheus-nginx-pathchange-strimzi
  namespace: monitoring
spec:
  rules:
  - host: prometheus-nginx-pathchange
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: prometheus-operated
            port:
              number: 9090
        path: "/prometheus(/|$)(.*)"
        pathType: Prefix
```

Backend Service

```
Karans-MacBook-Pro:ingress-ns karanalang$ kc describe svc prometheus-operated -n monitoring
Name:              prometheus-operated
Namespace:         monitoring
Labels:            operated-prometheus=true
Annotations:       cloud.google.com/neg: {"ingress":true}
                   cloud.google.com/neg-status:
                     {"network_endpoint_groups":{"9090":"k8s1-45a575f7-monitoring-prometheus-operated-9090-d19ceff1"},"zones":["us-east1-b"]}
Selector:          app.kubernetes.io/name=prometheus
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                None
IPs:               None
Port:              web  9090/TCP
TargetPort:        web/TCP
Endpoints:         <none>
Session Affinity:  None
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age                  From            Message
  ----    ------  ----                 ----            -------
  Normal  Detach  55m                  neg-controller  Detach 2 network endpoint(s) (NEG "k8s1-45a575f7-monitoring-prometheus-operated-9090-d19ceff1" in zone "us-east1-b")
  Normal  Detach  23m (x525 over 16h)  neg-controller  Detach 1 network endpoint(s) (NEG "k8s1-45a575f7-monitoring-prometheus-operated-9090-d19ceff1" in zone "us-east1-b")
  Normal  Attach  16m (x527 over 16h)  neg-controller  Attach 1 network endpoint(s) (NEG "k8s1-45a575f7-monitoring-prometheus-operated-9090-d19ceff1" in zone "us-east1-b")
```

when i do a curl, it gives - 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable

```
Karans-MacBook-Pro:ingress-ns karanalang$ curl prometheus-nginx-pathchange/prometheus
<html>
<head><title>503 Service Temporarily Unavailable</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>503 Service Temporarily Unavailable</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, pls note :
In the prometheus.yaml,
the following is added :

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: Prometheus
metadata:
  name: prometheus
  labels:
    app: strimzi
spec:
  externalUrl: 'http://prometheus-nginx-pathchange/prometheus/'
  routePrefix: '/'
```

Any ideas on how to debug/fix this issue ?
tia!

UPDATE :
i added TLS certs, and here is the output of the curl command

```
Karans-MacBook-Pro:ingress-ns karanalang$ curl -v -L prometheus-nginx-pathchange/prometheus
*   Trying 104.196.128.221...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to prometheus-nginx-pathchange (104.196.128.221) port 80 (#0)
> GET /prometheus HTTP/1.1
> Host: prometheus-nginx-pathchange
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 308 Permanent Redirect
< Date: Wed, 19 Jan 2022 18:57:39 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 164
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: https://prometheus-nginx-pathchange/prometheus
< 
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host prometheus-nginx-pathchange left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://prometheus-nginx-pathchange/prometheus'
*   Trying 104.196.128.221...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to prometheus-nginx-pathchange (104.196.128.221) port 443 (#1)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, unknown CA (560):
* SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
* Closing connection 1
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
* Closing connection 0
```

Pls note : i'm using a self-signed cert, any ideas on how to fix this ?

Comment: Is this somehow connected to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70692202/) or it's different issue? Did you try to change your path from `path: "/prometheus(/|$)(.*)"` to `path: "/prometheus"`? Also do you want to use `rewrite` annotation?

Comment: @PjoterS - changing the path to "/prometheus" does not fix the issue, the objective is to use the re-write option so Prometheus is available on endpoint /prometheus ``` http://hostname/prometheus ```  , hope that clarifies

Comment: @PjoterS - pls let me know if you have any suggestions on how to debug/fix this ? thnx

Comment: Did you try to use rewrite `/$1` instread of '/$2` and use `path: /?(.*)`? I would need to replicate this on my env. Could you provide steps you have followed to setup your environment?